# How to change location point on google maps dynamically using longitude and latitude coordinates without reload the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-maps

Have a look.

**Trying/way to achieve:**

[image: here]

**Left hand sided:** Google Maps that's supposed to display the location on the bases of the LON, LAT when I select table rows on (right side). But without reloading the page.

**Right hand sided:** there is a table which contains LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE values that are coming from MySQL DB.

**My Approach:**

```
  <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="mapouter">
                        <div class="gmap_canvas">
                            <iframe width="600" height="500" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=32.7333,74.8667&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
                        </div>              
                    </div>
            </div>

          <div class="col-md-6" >
             <table class="table " style="margin-left: 30px;"> 
                <tbody>

              <?php 

                 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
                 {
                    $lat =$row['lat']; 
                    $lon =$row['lon'];


                  <tr class="bg-success">

                    <td><?php  echo $lat;?></td>
                    <td><?php  echo $lon;?></td>

                  </tr >

                  <?php
                 }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
```

I am not sure how this can be accomplished in jquery, sorry to say but I am a beginner at jquery.

**Questions:**

- I am not sure at all if this approach is the best practice for
  this or not.
- Is it possible, if so, how ?
- Can anyone help me shed light upon this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a click event for all your 'tr' tags, get values for lon and lat from 'td', replace non-numeric text and change html inside .gmap_canvas div, which wrapped your iframe.

here your code https://jsfiddle.net/mshz0gvu/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="mapouter">
      <div class="gmap_canvas">
        <iframe width="100%" height="500" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=32.7333,74.8667&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
      </div>              
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" >
    <table class="table " style="margin-left: 30px;"> 
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>LAT: 42.3145186</td>
          <td>LON: -71.110367</td>
        </tr >
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$('tr').click(function(){
    let lat = $(this).find('td:first-child').text().replace('LAT: ', '');
    let lon = $(this).find('td:last-child').text().replace('LON: ', '');
    let new_map = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"500\" id=\"gmap_canvas\" src=\"https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+lat+","+lon+"&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\"></iframe>";
    $('div.gmap_canvas').html(new_map);
});
</script>
```

Comment: code-only answers are highly discouraged here, please consider improving this post by explaining how this answers OP's question in order not to get this flagged as low-quality

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer, my query is resolved